# Git: How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, public-key

I'm on Mac Snow Leopard and I just installed `git`.

I just tried

```
git clone git@thechaw.com:cakebook.git
```

but that gives me this error:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in `/Users/username/Documents/cakebook/.git/`
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What am I missing?
I've also tried doing `ssh-keygen` with no passphase but still same error.

Comment: have you tried to upload the public key that you have generated via ssh-keygen?

Comment: My problem was that I tried clone from `sudo` - this is another user with another public key.

Comment: same error. I previously created a public key through github, then generated another key-pair with the `ssh-keygen` utility. Deleting the old public key in personal settings on github and adding my ssh generated id_rsa.pub key to SSH and GPG keys fixed the cloning permission issues.

Comment: If you're running bash screen and have done everything in every available website, there's a high chance you might have logged out from the session you created the screen session. A quick workaround is to restart the screen session: see https://superuser.com/q/180148

Comment: There's a page in the documentation that offers some guidance - https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 1306, accepted):

**If the user has not generated a ssh public/private key pair set before**

This info is working on theChaw but can be applied to all other git repositories which support SSH pubkey authentications. (See [gitolite][1], gitlab or github for example.)

> First start by setting up your own public/private key pair set. This
> can use either DSA or RSA, so basically any key you setup will work.
> On most systems you can use ssh-keygen.

> - First you'll want to cd into your .ssh directory. Open up the terminal and run:
>
> > `cd ~/.ssh && ssh-keygen`
>
> - Next you need to copy this to your clipboard.
> - On OS X run: `cat id_rsa.pub | pbcopy`
> - On Linux run: `cat id_rsa.pub | xclip`
> - On Windows (via Cygwin/Git Bash) run: `cat id_rsa.pub | clip`
> - On Windows (Powershell) run: `Get-Content id_rsa.pub | Set-Clipboard` (Thx to @orion elenzil)
> - Add your key to your account via the website.
> - Finally setup your .gitconfig.
> - `git config --global user.name "bob"`
> - `git config --global user.email bob@...`
>   (don't forget to restart your command line to make sure the config is reloaded)
>
> That's it you should be good to clone and checkout.

Further information can be found at https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys (thanks to @Lee Whitney)
[1]: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

-

**If the user has generated a ssh public/private key pair set before**

- check which key have been authorized on your github or gitlab account settings
- determine which corresponding private key must be associated from your local computer

`eval $(ssh-agent -s)`

- define where the keys are located

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Ok. This is actually not a git but an ssh synchronization problem. I got the same with Assembla and you link helped me resolving it. 

Thanks !

Comment: This answer is helpful but this seems more complete and just as easy if you are generating keys from scratch: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: I experienced a problem with the keygen. It is sensitive to the email address in a global env variable. In case you are having this problem, you will want to specify the email address for your github account in the first step:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"

Comment: cat id_rsa.pub | xclip produces error "Error: Can't open display: (null)", alternatively execute command "cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" to get the public key.

Comment: just use the cat command, und copy the content to your clipboard (CTRL-C) yourself.

Comment: Will ssh-keygen overwrite my existing key?

Comment: Thank you, Sir! I bit the bullet and just did it & it worked! But it seems like a github bug because I have this with one repo; the same repo works fine with a new local clone. The old ssh key is only a few months old and stll valid. Hrrrrmmmm.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, you'll need to `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: @MichaelLitvin And if that still doesn't work, then you need to `ssh-add -K <path to private key>`. This is needed if you have a passphrase and want the macOS KeyChain be used to provide the password automatically.

Comment: Copying using `xclip` on Linux only worked by doing the following `xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` which is listed here: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: Shouldn't you add the key to the ssh agent somewhere in there, like they do in the default github instructions you see in any empty repo on GH?

Comment: These commands only work in the git bash prompt.  For windows you most likely will need to be in your c:/users/<YourUser>/.ssh directory. and also name your key "is_rsa".

Comment: its noted in the commands where they work, in the case of windows is clearly states git bash or cygwin. the name of the key does not matter. you should also use `ecdsa` instead of `rsa`

Comment: thanks for your answer. One thing I would like to ask is why do I have to use `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` after rebooting the system every time? Is there a work around to this problem?

Comment: On Mac see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140075/ssh-add-is-not-persistent-between-reboots

Comment: After upgrading to mac os 10.15.5 I started having this same issue with github.com. I resolved it with `ssh-add  ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: what does the line `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` do?

Comment: Using GitBash as a command prompt helped instead of using Windows Command promt. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me but not on the first try. Even after trying these commands, making sure I have the correct SSH key in both local repo and Github account and restarting Windows terminal, I still got the same error. I closed the Windows terminal and used Git Bash and everything worked as expected.

Comment: if you're using PowerShell, that 'copy to your clipboard' step can be `cat id_rsa.pub | Set-Clipboard`, or to be even more powershelly, `Get-Content id_rsa.pub | Set-Clipboard`.

Comment: I don't understand why we have to add the email address?  I have another account that is my personal account.  I used 2 different email addresses.

Comment: @BrianWiley its not needed for the service itself - github and so on know who you are via your key. Git itself wants a email adress an an author name. but you could also use something like <> for example.

Comment: "unable to start ssh-agent service, error :1058"

Comment: @Pascallv - maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113738/starting-ssh-agent-on-windows-10-fails-unable-to-start-ssh-agent-service-erro

Comment: I try it doesn't work, then I try again with file name "id_rsa" then it's work !

Comment: I've been using Unity, and have been trying to install a package via the Package Manager using git - this gave me the error that everyone's been having in the post. This answer SO nearly worked for me! I tried a lot of things, but I believe that in the end, the thing that worked: not setting a password for the SSH that you create.

Comment: Superb resolved it

Answer (score 321):

More extensive troubleshooting and even automated fixing can be done with:

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

Alternatively, according to below comments, we could issue:

```
ssh -vT git@gitlab.com
```

or substitute gitlab/github with whatever Git Instance your organisation is running.

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

Comment: This did a ton of things, and then at the end I noticed 'authenticated successfully', tried `git pull` and it was fine again.

Comment: My problem had to do with having a different key for my server. Once I used the above command to determine the issue, I fixed the IdentifyFile in my config file and it worked.

Comment: Showed which key github was trying to use to authenticate. v helpful

Comment: This doesn't fix anything.  I still get the error in OP's question.

Comment: ssh -vT git@gitlab.com fixed it for me.

Comment: I tried and still get the issue as OP. It read *You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access*

Comment: The command is there to help you troubleshoot the issue, it isn't a magic fix-this-for-me switch.

Comment: I can't say this solved anything, but it is a hell of an interesting command and works with GitHub Enterprise as well.

Comment: In my case `ssh -vT git@gitlab.com` on Windows showed me that it was looking for an rsa key but I only had a dsa key in my .ssh directory.

Comment: Thank you! By running your provided command, I found my `~/.ssh/config` was modified by some other testing program and wasn't recover back. So I just deleted my `~/.ssh/config` and fix the issue. Cheers!

Comment: You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. What does that mean?

Comment: Make sure you are trying `ssh` to the correct host. For example, I added the public key correctly to my github account but I was on githubenterprise.com instead of github.com, and therefore, `ssh -vT git@<yourcompanyname>.githubenterprise.com` works but `ssh -vT git@github.com` continues to fail.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this magic command. It showed me that ssh was using the wrong ID, even after deleteing all with `ssh-add -D`.

Comment: If `ssh` connects fine, you might want to switch the ssh binary git uses with `git config --global core.sshCommand /usr/bin/ssh`

Comment: debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: this help me to find that my error was related to ssh key permissions were too open. I set them to 600 and now it is working

Comment: this is helpfull. i was looking for such command for a long time

Answer (score 228):

This error can happen when you are accessing the SSH URL (Read/Write) instead of Git Read-Only URL but you have no write access to that repo.

Sometimes you just want to clone your own repo, e.g. deploy to a server. In this case you actually only need READ-ONLY access. But since that's *your own* repo, GitHub may display SSH URL if that's your preference. In this situation, if your remote host's public key is not in your GitHub SSH Keys, your access will be denied, **which is expected to happen**.

An equivalent case is when you try cloning someone else's repo to which you have no write access with SSH URL.

In a word, **if your intent is to clone-only a repo, use HTTPS URL** (`https://github.com/{user_name}/{project_name}.git`) instead of SSH URL (`git@github.com:{user_name}/{project_name}.git`), which avoids (unnecessary) public key validation.

---

Update: GitHub is displaying HTTPS as the default protocol now and this move can probably reduce possible misuse of SSH URLs.

Comment: With the `https://github.com` git url, it still says `SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain`.  `git -c http.sslVerify=false clone ...` seems like a dangerous move.  Chrome doesn't give any ssl warnings though.  Thoughts?

Comment: @uosɐſ Sorry but I never encountered this problem. Maybe the first thing to do is to try the same command from a different machine and see if the problem persists.

Comment: This did it for me, too. Thanks.

In order to clone my git repo onto my shared hosting account (1and1) I had to use  

  `git clone https://github.com/MyUserName/MyRepo.git`

Simply click on the text links beneath the repo URL to the right of the Github page where it says "_You can clone with  HTTPS, SSH, or Subversion._". (Click _HTTPS_ to get the link instead of the default _SSH_.)

Comment: I had this exact same issue; I have (write) access to a public-facing repo with an SSH key but needed read-only access to clone LFS objects. Replacing the ssh address with the HTTPS URL solved my issue.

Comment: I don't understand.. why does SSL URL require both read AND write permissions to clone?

Answer (score 180):

The github help [link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) helped me sort out this problem. Looks like the ssh key was not added to the ssh-agent. This is what I ended up doing.

*Command 1:*

Ensure ssh-agent is enabled. The command starts the ssh-agent in the background:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

*Command 2:*

Add your SSH key to the ssh-agent:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: After upgrade to OSx El Capitan to Sierra this worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me on Raspberry Pi, where ssh-add has a "-k" flag instead of "-K", apparently. But once I added my deployment key, I was able to successfully clone my repo using its SSH link.

Comment: This is the **real solution** and it was copied+pasted to the accepted answer 4 years later (on [Jan 11 ' 19](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2643584/revisions)), so this deserves all our upvotes!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent. See if you can find something here or just restart your system and see if it works.

Comment: "Adding the SSH key to the ssh-agent" solved my problem!

Comment: Command 2 works for me.  Before doing this, it asks for my passphrase, which I had to enter by hand.  When the command is within `npm`, it fails.

Comment: Using ssh-add did the trick, no idea why git does not auto add the keys by default.

Answer (score 135):

Another possibility on Windows, which is not covered in any of these answers, and is not covered in the git or github docs on troubleshooting:

git may be using a different openssh executable than you think it is.

I was receiving the `Permission denied (public key)` error when trying to clone or pull from github and ssh.dev.azure.com, and I'd followed all the instructions and verified that my SSH keys were setup correctly (from SSH's standpoint) using `ssh -vT git@github.com` and `ssh -vT git@ssh.dev.azure.com`. And was still getting these errors:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I eventually figured out that the problem is that Git for Windows, and Windows, both have their own versions of openssh. This is documented here: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5641

I was relying on the Windows ssh-agent service to store my ssh key passphrases, so git (with it's separate version of openssh) couldn't read my private keys. I consider it a bug that this error message is used - it's misleading.

The fix was:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe'"
```

Or in your ~/.gitconfig:

```
[core]
    sshCommand = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe'
```

Perhaps this will be fixed in git for Windows soon, but this is the 2nd time I've wasted time on this issue.

Comment: This also resolved it for me.  Strange only one of my visual studio solutions, when I utilized Package Manager Console,  with `git pull` I'd receive"Permission Denied (publickey)".  However, on other Visual Studio solutions (projects of mine), I wouldn't have any problems... This solution makes sense, how the problem originated for only one of my projects is still a bit of a mystery.

Comment: Or you can modify `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig` instead, if you use Cygwin git in parallel and want to leave `~/.gitconfig` as-is.

Comment: This issue still exists on win11 (at least after upgrade from win10). Thanks for the solution! Docs can't help with it

Comment: Choose "Use external OpenSSH" instead of the default option "Use bundled OpenSSH" in the installation process.

Comment: Another thank-you!  I ran into the same issue when updating to Git-2.35.1.2 (from Git-2.31.1), and this resolved it.

Comment: Thank goodness you're here! I suspected this may be a problem with some Git misconfiguration using the wrong storage, the same thing happens with GPG for Windows. This solved my issue!

Comment: Can confirm this is still an issue. I'm not sure why it started suddenly for me and only affected one of my local windows accounts and the other was working fine. Set in my config. Thanks

Comment: I was able to run it for mac as well. Just put the right path for ssh in mac. For me it was "/usr/bin/ssh"

Comment: This saved me a world of pain - Thank you

Comment: This is the answer if you clicked "Use bundled OpenSSH" during the installation. Thank you

Comment: Thanks this indeed resolved my problem

Comment: My issue was on windows and this was the perfect solution. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 116):

I was struggling with the same problem that's what I did and I was able to clone the repo. I followed this procedure for **Mac**.

**First Step: Checking if we already have the public SSH key.**

1. Open Terminal.
2. Enter `ls -al ~/.ssh` to see if existing SSH keys are present:

Check the directory list to see if you already have a public SSH key. Default public is one of the following d_dsa.pub, id_ecdsa.pub, id_ed25519.pub, id_rsa.pub.

If you don't find then go to step 2 otherwise follow step 3

**Step 2: Generating public SSH key**

1. Open Terminal.
2. Enter the following command with a valid email address that you use for github `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`
3. You will see the following in your terminal `Generating public/private rsa key pair`. When it prompts to`"Enter a file in which to save the key,"` press Enter. This accepts the default file location. When it prompts to `Enter a file in which to save the key (/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa): [Press enter]` Just press enter again.
4. At the prompt, `"Type a secure passphrase. Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]"` press enter if you don't want to `Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]` press enter again

This will generate `id_rsa.pub`

**Step 3: Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent**

1. Interminal type `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
2. Add your SSH key to the ssh-agent. If you are using an existing SSH key rather than generating a new SSH key, you'll need to replace id_rsa in the command with the name of your existing private key file. Enter this command `$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
3. Now copy the SSH key and also add it to you github account
4. In terminal enter this command with your ssh file name `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` This will copy the file to your clipboard
   Now open you github account Go to **Settings > SSH and GPG keys > New SSH key** Enter title and paste the key from clipboard and save it. Voila you're done.

Comment: Windows user copy via :  cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip

Comment: Finally after reading here and there for an hour, step by step solution....works great. Remember to add your github password as the passphrase in the steps otherwise will have to add manually everytime

Comment: Great answer. I would also add it was helpful for me to get info on how to change my remote git details -- see this link for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63830575/1818235

Comment: Thank you! This worked well for me, except:
instead of ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
I ran ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
The "-K" option prompted for a PIN, which I don't have.

Comment: As of macOS Ventura, ed25519, instead of RSA, will have to be used instead.

Comment: This was awesome, I had tried many ways but all in wain... but this worked for me

Comment: what if the terminal request for A PIN ? What is that for?

Comment: same as  StvnBrkdll, -K asked for a PIN. Instead, (as suggested here https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2318#issuecomment-1166828838) using lower case -k asked for the passphrase (as in step 2) - Great help from this answer, anyhow - thanks

Comment: really helpful, step by step solution, thank you for this

Answer (score 105):

Got the same error report.

Fixed with using the **HTTPS** instead of the **SSH** protocol. Since I don't want to set "SSH keys" for a test PC.

Change URL to HTTPS when clone:

```
git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

**My problem is a little bit different**: I have the URL set to **SSH** when adding an existing local repo to remote, by using:

```
git remote add origin ssh://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

To fix it, reset the URL to **HTTPS**:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

BTW, you may check your URL using the command:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Hope this will help some one like me. :D

Comment: I did it this way. It was all ok till I wanted to push an amended commit... and it failed. I got stuck, as no new commits could be used because it's protected against such activity.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why my repo was suddenly configured for SSH, I had only ever used HTTPS so I'm glad you proposed this fix.

Answer (score 47):

This works for me:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: thanks, it worked. to explain the same step by step I have added a step-by-step approach to my answer.

Answer (score 38):

### Visual guide (Windows)

#### 1 of 2. Git batch side

**1.1.** Open **git batch** (Download [her](https://git-scm.com/downloads))
[image]

**1.2.** **Paste** the text below (Change to your GitHub account email)

```html
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

[image]

**1.3.** Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Accepts the default file location)
[image]

**1.4.** Click <kbd>Enter</kbd> Twice (Or set SSH key passphrases - [Gitbub passphrases docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases))

```json
> Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]
> Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]
```

**1.5. The key generate:**

> Your identification has been saved in /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa...

**1.6.** <kbd>Copy</kbd> the SSH key to your clipboard.

`$ clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

#### 2 of 2. Github website user side

Under `user setting`
[image]

`SSH and GPG keys` => **New SSH key**:
[image]

<kbd>Paste</kbd> the code from step `1.6`
[image]

**Done :)**

[image]

---

If someone doesn't want to use SSH `use HTTPS` :

[image]

**Github docs:** https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Answer (score 31):

**If your problem appears out of the blue recently (the latter half of 2021), it may have been caused by incompatible hash algorithms.**

As of this post (Oct 2021), the latest version of Git for windows is 2.33.1 ([release note](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.33.1.windows.1)), who has embraced the latest OpenSSH 8.8p1 ([release note](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html)), *who in turn has deprecated SHA-1*. Meanwhile, if your remote Git repository still sticks to SHA-1, you'll fail the authentication.

To see whether you could have fallen into this case, check the version of your software by:

```sh
ssh -V
git --version
```

Then you should check the "Potentially-incompatible changes" section of [OpenSSH 8.8/8.8p release note](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html).

**TL;DR**

**Solution 1:** Enable SHA-1 again by adding this to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host <remote>
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Remember to replace `<remote>` with the hostname of your remote repository.

**Solution 2:** Regenerate your key pair using ECDSA or Ed25519, instead of RSA. For example:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -C <comment>
```

Remember to replace `<comment>` with your own mnemonic phrase. Then, upload the generated public key to your remote repository.

---

FYI, I encountered this prompt message when accessing Gitee.com, who uses `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` on their server and has posted a page on this issue [here](https://gitee.com/help/articles/4352) (in Mandarin).

```
git@gitee.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: I used Solution 2. Now I'm able to access to remote repo. Thanks a lot. That solution works for Git, TrotoiseGit and SourceTree configured to Git ssh instead of embedded one.

Answer (score 26):

Note that (at least for some projects) **you must have a github account with an ssh key**.

Look at the keys listed in your authentication agent (*ssh-add -l*)
  (if you don't see any, add one of your existing keys with ssh-add /path/to/your/key (eg: *ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa*))
  (if you don't have any keys, first create one. See: http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html or just google ssh-keygen)

**To verify that you have a key associated with your github account**:

Go to: https://github.com/settings/ssh

You should see at least one key with a hash key matching one of the hashes you saw when you typed *ssh-add -l* just a minute ago.

If you don't, add one, then try again.

Comment: You know you have this problem if you have been asked to connect with an SSH key (url looks like `git@github.company.com` instead of `https://github.company.com`) but your Github settings don't have an SSH key. Github supplies step-by-step directions at https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent.

Answer (score 26):

**Please try this if nothing is worked out**

1. Generate personal Access token (`Setting -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens -> Generate new token`)
2. `git remote set-url origin https://<TOEKN>@github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

Note: If a password popup comes, try to enter the token only (try twice)

Comment: This is one of the easiest ways i found to clone a repo. Thank you.


git clone https://<TOEKN>@github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git

Comment: when Nothing will work.. this will work

Comment: worked fine, thanks

Comment: this helped me.

Answer (score 20):

These are the steps I followed in windows 10

1. Open Git Bash.
2. Generate Public Key:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremailaddress@xyz.com"
   ```
3. Copy generated key to the clipboard (works like CTRL+C)

   ```
   clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```
4. Browser, go to Github => Profile=> Settings => SSH and GPG keys => Add Key
5. Provide the key name and paste clipboard (CTRL+V).
6. Finally, test your connection (Git bash)

   ```
   ssh -T git@github.com
   ```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I met the same issue because of I was thought the difference between **SSH** and **HTTPS** is

`https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

`ssh://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

So I changed from **HTTPS** to **SSH** just by changing `https://` to `ssh://` nothing on the end of the url was changed.

But the truth is:

```
https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git

git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Which means I changed `ssh://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` to `git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` it works.

Stupid error but hope helps someone!

Comment: yes, i changed `ssh://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` to `git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` it works.

Comment: I see because i just use `ssh` instead of `https` so i just changed 'https://' to 'ssh://` then i got the error. So change 'ssh://git/../` to 'git@../" : ) Edited my answer.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you very much! I tried https and then ssh but it still keeps denying my access until make it your way with "git clone git@github.com:/myusername/myproject.git".

Answer (score 13):

I had a slight different situation, I was logged on to a remote server and was using git on the server, when I ran any git command I got the same message

```
   Permission denied (publickey).
   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The way I fixed it was by changing the file /etc/ssh_config on my Mac. 
from

```
ForwardAgent no
```

to

```
ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: The error was occurring while trying to fetch gems from github from a VirtualBox VM. Updated my Vagrantfile to use `config.ssh.forward_agent = true`, restarted the VM, and now it works.

Comment: Might not be the best choice in terms of security according to this:  https://heipei.github.io/2015/02/26/SSH-Agent-Forwarding-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 11):

##### ALWAYS CHECK GITHUB FOR SSH-KEYS GENERATION PROCEDUR, NOT SOME OUTDATED BLOG

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

There you can see that keys are generated with:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

So algorithm is **ed25519** not rsa or anything else.

Comment: I used some old RSA Keys which didnt worked out because it has to be ed25519 as you stated. Thanks a lot for this hint. Your command did the trick, using no password.

Answer (score 10):

Solution using `gh` i.e. [Github's official CLI](https://cli.github.com/)

#### gh installation

`brew install gh`

#### gh login or authentication via cli

`gh auth login`

#### repo clone

`gh repo clone <username or orgname>/<repo-name>`

Example: `gh repo clone keshavdulal/sample-repo`

*Rant: I too was bashing my head when `git clone` suddenly decided not to work anymore and I don't have the patience or brainpower to relearn ssh/public keys/cryptography from scratch just to clone a freaking repo I already have access to. Also surprised no one mentioned `gh` in the answers yet*

Answer (score 9):

I had to copy my ssh keys to the root folder.
Google Cloud Compute Engine running Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo cp ~/.ssh/* /root/.ssh/
```

Answer (score 8):

Are you in a [corporate environment](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2293#issuecomment-38010146)?  Is it possible that your system variables have recently changed?  Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226147/where-does-github-for-windows-keep-its-ssh-key) SO answer, ssh keys live at `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`.  So if `%HOMEDRIVE%` recently changed, git doesn't know where to look for your key, and thus all of the authentication stuff.

Try running `ssh -vT git@github.com`.  Take note of where the `identity file` is located.  For me, that was pointing *not* to my normal `\Users\MyLogin` but rather to a network drive, because of a change to environment variables pushed at the network level.

The solution?  Since my new `%HOMEDRIVE%` has the same permissions as my local files, I just moved my .ssh folder there, and called it a day.

Comment: this work for me. yesterday my ssh key working but today some setting of my system get changed. I just add shh key again and it's working now.

Comment: You moved your ssh folder into the corporate network?

Answer (score 8):

Guys this is how it worked for me:

1. Open terminal and go to user [See attached image]
2. Open .ssh folder and make sure it doesn't have any file like id_rsa or id_rsa.pub otherwise sometimes it wont properly rewrite files
3. git --version [Check for git installation and version]
4. git config --global user.email "your email id"
5. git config --global user.name "your name"
6. git config --list [make sure you have set your name & email]
7. cd ~/.ssh
8. ssh-keygen, it prompts for saving file, allow it
9. cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  [Access your public key & copy the key to gerrit settings]

**Note**: You should not be using the sudo command with Git. If you have a very good reason you must use sudo, then ensure you are using it with every command (it's probably just better to use su to get a shell as root at that point). If you generate SSH keys without sudo and then try to use a command like sudo git push, you won't be using the same keys that you generated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot -name changed in git repo to  Deploy keys in repo setting

Answer (score 7):

I hit this error because I needed to give my present working directory permissions 700:

```
chmod -R 700 /home/ec2-user/
```

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, make sure all your apps agree on HOME.  Msys will surprisingly NOT do it for you. I had to set an environment variable because ssh and git couldn't seem to agree on where my .ssh directory was.

Answer (score 6):

**One of the easiest way**

go to terminal-

```
  git push <Git Remote path> --all
```

Comment: what is remote path here?

Answer (score 6):

I helped the following:

1. Open Terminal (*Git Bash*)
2. Remove all files in directory `.ssh` or rename and create new `.ssh` folder.
3. To follow in the steps of the instructions:

   1. [Generating a new SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key)
   2. [Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)

System: Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

The basic GIT instructions did not make a reference to the SSH key stuff. Following some of the links above, I found a git help page that explains, step-by-step, exactly how to do this for various operating systems (the link will detect your OS and redirect, accordingly):

http://help.github.com/set-up-git-redirect/

It walks through everything needed for GITHub and also gives detailed explanations such as "why add a passphrase when creating an RSA key." I figured I'd post it, in case it helps someone else...

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution to this, when you are trying to push to a repository with a different username is:

```
 git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME@github.com/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git
```

Answer (score 4):

Its pretty straight forward. Type the below command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremailid@yourdomain.com"
```

Generate the SSH key. Open the file and copy the contents. Go to GitHub setting page , and click on SSH key . Click on Add new SSH key, and paste the contents here. That's it :) You shouldn't see the issue again.

Answer (score 4):

I deleted node_modules/ package-lock.json and yarn.lock files. Ran `npm i` again. This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

### This is how I was finally able to push to git

---

For me, I keep on getting

```
git@github.com: Permission denied 
fatal: Could not read from remote 

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So after hours of research, I discovered that after ***[generating your ssh key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key)*** and [**making your windows agent recognise your key**](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) the last thing I did to fix my issue was to [**update the ssh-key in the git repo**](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) for that project.

So you would log in to your git hub account then go to the repo you want to push to then in the settings look for security that's where you can add your ssh key. For me, the key is stored in a .ssh/id_ed123939.pub

Answer (score 4):

If you are using POWERSHELL and were having issues to run git commands with an existing private key like me... then these instructions will come in handy (I just made it work):

Assuming you [already have a private key generated](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) "some_key" in your `.ssh` folder (for example `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"` ) ; then:

- Open a powershell terminal with elevated access / as administrator
- Run these commands

`Get-Service -Name ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual`

`Start-Service ssh-agent`

- Add the generated private key to the agent:

`ssh-add C:\Users\yourUser\.ssh\some_key`

When cloning the remote repo add the `-c core.sshCommand` option in the command in order to set a custom ssh command for authenticating on the remote repo.

EG.

`git clone -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i C:\\Users\\yourUser\\.ssh\\some_key" git@github.com:REMOTE_REPO.git`

After that you should be able to pull and push from the repo with no issues.

Alternatively, one can configure the ~/.ssh/config file with the following contents

```
Host github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile C:\Users\yourUser\.ssh\some_key
```

If the ssh-agent service is set to run manually, then it must be started up again upon reboot.

Hope this helps

Comment: why the key is not explicitly visible? it should be configured in .\.ssh\known_hosts. (All the slashes in path needs to be doubled).

Comment: ~/.ssh/config edit was missing. I Updated the answer with more content.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Rufinus' reply, the shortcut to copy your ssh key to the clipboard in **Windows** is:

- `type id_rsa.pub | clip`

Refs:

- [Print to standard output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235362/which-windows-shell-command-will-print-a-file-content-on-the-standard-output-li)
- [Copy command line output to clipboard](http://www.labnol.org/software/copy-command-output-to-clipboard/2506/)

Answer (score 3):

I have just experienced this issue while setting my current project, and none of the above solution works. so i tried looking what's really happening on the debug list using the command ssh -vT git@github.com. I notice that my private key filename is not on the list. so renaming the private key filename to 'id_rsa' do the job. hope this could help.

Comment: Not helpful in cases when you're **using** the "id_rsa" key for anything else....

Comment: This was my exact issue! It seems that, in my case, I had renamed the file containing my private key, which prevented the ssh agent from find it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than one key you may need to do 
`ssh-add private-keyfile`

Comment: [root@li566-238 hanjiyun]# ssh-add private-keyfile
private-keyfile: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

You could begin by doing the following in the terminal:

1. cd ~/.ssh
2. Generate an ssh key by running: ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -C "your@email.com"
3. When prompted to enter where to save the key, enter: cat id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
4. Enter and confirm your passphrase which will then generate your new key.
5. Inform github about the key by running: cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
6. Copy the output then head over to github to create a new SSH key. Paste the copied content into the text area, give it a befitting title then hit the ADD KEY button.

Now you can go about your operations hassle-free.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me.

Your public key is saved to the id_rsa.pub;file and is the key you upload to your account. You can save this key to the clipboard by running this:

> pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

- copy the SSH key to the clipboard, return to the web portal.
- In the SSH Key field, paste your SSH key.
- In the Name field, provide a name for the key.
- save .

Answer (score 2):

In my MAC I solved this with:

```
cp ~/.ssh/github_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

For some reason my git stopped to find the private key in the `github_rsa` file. This happened in a specific repo. I mean that in other repositories git kept working normally.

I think it's a bug.

I could find this behavior running `ssh -vT git@github.com`

Answer (score 2):

In MAC, go to Terminal

1) Navigate to Home Directory using command - `cd ~`

2) cd .ssh && ssh-keygen (For Defaults, click on Enter/Return key for both inputs)

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa):      
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /Users/usernmae/.ssh/id_rsa.
```

3) After that , Do "`ls`". you will find id_rsa.pub file.

4) Copy the contents in the id_rsa.pub file (read using the cat command - `cat id_rsa.pub`)

5) Navigate to BitBucket or any version tool which supports the SSH keys. Paste the contents using the **Add Key** Option

That's it. Try to commit and push now.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me the actual problem is using text editor to copy the SSH public key to clipboard

If you follow [docs.github.com](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) and open .pub file in text editor like Notepad++ to copy SSH public key, Then you will be in trouble.

[image]

Instead use

> cat ~/.ssh/id_***.pub | clip

command to copy

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue today while trying to setup an existing repository in windows using git bash. The problem was when typing the following:

```
git clone myreposshurl
```

In gitbash, ctrl+c and ctrl+v doesn't work. While trying to paste the repository url, I did ctrl+v which introduced some unwanted characters. Finally found and solved the issue when I tried and succeeded cloning another repository. Took 1.5 hours to figure out this stupid mistake.

```
\302\226git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

If you see characters like \302 like above then this could be one possible cause.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar **Permission denied (publickey) error** when trying to run a makefile.

As an alternative to the SSH steps above, you can Install the native GitHub for Mac application.

Click **Download GitHub for Mac** from - https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-mac

Once you complete setup with your git hub account (I also installed the git hub command line tools but unsure if this step is required or not) then I received an email -

**[GitHub] A new public key was added to your account**

and my error was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. My problem was mixing in sudo.

I couldn't create the directory I was cloning into automatically without prefixing the git clone command with sudo.  When I did that, however, my ssh keys where not being properly referenced.

To fix it, I set permissions via chmod on the parent directory I wanted to contain my clone so I could write to it.  Then I ran git clone WITHOUT a sudo prefix.  It then worked!  I changed the permissions back after that. Done.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because I generated the ssh keys with the wrong email. I was able to connect using ssh, but not using git. The solution was to regenerate the keys using the main email address of my github account.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me

```
ssh -i [your id_rsa path] -T github@github.com
```

Comment: You'd rather explain why your answer would solve his problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This strange error, in my case was a symptom of `gnome-keyring-daemon` incorrectly naming the key to which it required a password.

I follow the steps outlined here, and entered the password via the terminal. The error, aka the confounding GUI interface, was resolved.
See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3045/how-to-disable-gnome-keyring

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have reinstalled ubuntu and the user name is changed from previous. In this case the the generated ssh key also differs from the previous one.

The issue solved by just copy the current ssh public key, in the repository. The key will be available in your user's `/home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cd ~
$ cd .ssh
$ chmod 400 id_rsa
```

Comment: Load key id_rsa: bad permissions
Permissions 0755 for id_rsa are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the terminal as admin.

If the terminal can't see your .ssh it will return that error.

Answer (score 1):

After did `ssh-keygen` part, you might check verification by below:

1. `$ ssh -T git@github.com` for testing your SSH connection;
2. Confirm which user ran "ssh-keygen" command. The public key you generated is followed by that user. The reason in below:

> **Should the sudo command be used with Git?**
>
> > You should not be using the sudo command with Git. If you have a very good reason you must use sudo, then ensure you are using it with every command (it's probably just better to use su to get a shell as root at that point). If you generate SSH keys without sudo and then try to use a command like sudo git push, you won't be using the same keys that you generated.

3. Confirm you have write permission for the dir that repository  will clone to. If not then do it. And you must refresh current user by logout or `su` etc after updating user group permission.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ssh link from Github but make sure to not append it with ssh just use what the ssh tab on git hub gives you to clone your repo.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get over this issue by following below steps in my ubuntu system. As i was experimenting with passwordless ssh to the system.

sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

1) Commented below : 
   #Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
   #PasswordAuthentication yes
    PasswordAuthentication no ----> commented this.

2) Then restarted the sshd daemon as below.

service sshd restart

Answer (score 0):

Steps for Mac:

1. Switch user ( sudo su - jenkins)
2. Generate key ( ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "username") . Username
   is one with which you are using with jenkins.
3. Copy generated public key (cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub).
4. Paste the key to git account. (Settings -> SSH and CPG keys -> New
   ssh keys -> Enter name of the key (can be any) and paste the key to
   description).

Answer (score 0):

Let me share my experience too,

I was trying to clone some project from the Gerrit repo where I got my public keys in account settings.

On the first attempt to make `git clone` I got the following error:

```
Unable to negotiate with XX.XX.XX.XX port XXX: no matching key exchange
method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

I figured out that I need to pass the SSH option `-oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` somehow to `git clone`.

Hopefully `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable did the job:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"
```

But `git clone` still didn't start to work.. Now it throws the (on topic):

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I got already SSH keys and didn't want to regenerate them. I checked plain SSH connection to the host and it was ok:

```
****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****

  Hi XXXXX, you have successfully connected over SSH.

  Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
  To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

  git clone ssh://xxxxx@xx.xx.xx:xxx/REPOSITORY_NAME.git
```

I was confused a bit. I started again and turned on the debug for SSH via `-vvv` option. And I saw the following:

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

Possibly, it was an overhead for the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` env variable - my key was secured with passphrase (and I entered it when I was checking the login to the git repo host).

So, I decided to get rid of the phasphrase then. A simple command helped me:

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

Then I entered my passphrase for the "old passphrase" and just hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> twice on the "new passphare" to leave it empty i.e. with no passphrase at all and to confirm my choice.

After that I got the freshly cloned repo on my local disk.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend checking some standard things like:

- **login as the correct user** in your system,
- have the **right private key in the right location** in your system,
- try to connect with the correct **username**, **hostname**, and **port**,
- have **the public key in the right location (and for the right user)** in the external server,
- **restarted the ssh service** at your computer:

```
service ssh restart
```

(or in another way depending on how you manage services in your system...)

It was enough for me.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Why somebody gives me -1 vote? Maybe I can improve it, if I will know what is wrong with this current one? Please help me smebody, who know what could be wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$ service ssh restart`
bash: service: command not found

Comment: Hi @GirkovArpa, maybe this will help: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/restart-services-%27service%27-command-not-found-88809/

Answer (score 0):

I also had the exact same error.

The problem was that when copying the public key into BitBucket (in my case), a non-visible newline at the end was copy/pasted.

So when copying the public key, first copy it to notepad, remove the empty line at the end, copy it, and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible that public/private config is incorrect. please follow the steps to do it.
execute command anywhere in window

```
ssh-keygen -o -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

now go to the c://users/xyz/.ssh/ and open the id_rsa key (path can vary)
now go to the gitlab and userprofile> setting>ssh keys and add your key here.
now try clone

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was using `sudo`:

`sudo git clone git@github.com:userName/repo.git` was resulting in the error mentioned above.

So to fix this I chown the folder I was trying to clone into

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/iqge.org/html`

then using this
`git clone git@github.com:userName/repo.git` was successfully done

Answer (score 0):

**When ever I get a new computer at work or switch jobs these are steps I follow setup github access. Mac or Windows**

-Go to https://github.[yourWorkDomain].com.  navigate to    Settings → Developer Settings → Personal access tokens
-Generate a new token
-Set the token description and only check the “repo” box for scope (this will give you repo:status, repo_deployment, public_repo,    repo:invite access)

-After your are given the token, copy it (don't navigate away yet, confirm the next two steps work)
-Try to clone the repo again(using “https”)
-For the username use your Username
-For the password, paste the token you copied
-All future requests should work now without asking for your username and password.

Answer (score 0):

- **Make a new folder** Anywhere in your PC (ex. on desktop)
- Move to that new folder and open git bash there.

& Write Following Code there in bash:

> ```
> $ git init
> $ git remote add origin https://github.com/YOUR_GITHUB_HANDLER/YOUR_REPO_NAME.git
> $ git pull origin master
> ```

(See that new folder whether files are pulled or not)

If files are pulled, then first **Delete** all files/folders from that older folder (where the described error occurs) **including .git** folder

& Copy all files from new folder including .git and paste it to our older folder where the described error occurs.

This will fetch you remote repo.

**If you want to fetch remote repo without removing new changes which you have made locally, then only copy & paste our new .git folder**

Now you will able to do `$ git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

### **SourceTree** for Windows case

In case you use **SourceTree** on Windows you need to create a new keypair using **PuTTyGen**

[image]

The `ssh-rsa` key from the top section you should insert to

```
Github => Profile=> Settings => SSH and GPG keys => Add Key
```

Then save the private key and add it to `Pageant` (it runs with the SourceTree)

[image]

That's all

Answer (score 0):

I already authenticated with `gh`, created the new keys, and so on. The problem was that I installed `gh` with `snap` in Ubuntu, so the new key generated was in `./snap/gh/502/.ssh/` instead of the regular `.ssh` path.

I solved it copying everything to `.ssh` folder with:

```
cp -a ./snap/gh/502/.ssh/* .ssh/
```

If not, find your keys with `find . -name *.pub`

It's still a problem in the digital world to know where you left your keys, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution for WSL2

1. Open WSL terminal and paste this. It will generate a key.
   `cd ~/.ssh && ssh-keygen`
2. It will ask for the file name. Leave it empty so it's gonna save as default `id_rsa.pub`
3. Run this command to copy the key to clipboard.
   `cat id_rsa.pub | clip.exe`
4. Open https://github.com/settings/keys page to add copiedd SSH key to your account.
5. Try to clone again.

Answer (score 0):

On PowerShell what worked for me was: `$env:GIT_SSH_COMMAND = 'ssh -i C:\\Users\\<User>\\.ssh\\<Private Key>'`

Answer (score -1):

Adding RSA key in GitHub using terminal:

MAC:

1. go to folder Users/ xxxx /.ssh
2. Run command: cd ~/.ssh && ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "github_email@id.com"
3. enter  file name as id_rsa
4. enter if ask passphrase
5. again enter
6. Run command eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
7. Open config file: open ~/.ssh/config
   if not exist then create as:
   touch ~/.ssh/config
8. Now open config file and add below lines in file:

Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

9. close the file
10. Add ssh private key to agent run command:
    ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
11. Now copy ssh key as:
    pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
12. Go to gitHub/BitBucket
13. Click to Manage accounts
14. Click on SSH key
15. Delete existing key
16. Click add key
17. Paste the copied key.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to add

```
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2
-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert
-v01@openssh.com
```

To file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/ciphers.conf

Solved by `ssh -vT git@github.com` showing error `Skipping ssh-ed25519 key ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 - corresponding algo not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms`

Answer (score -1):

**For those of you who using Xcode**

- Go to settings -> Accounts
- Add your Git/gitlab/bitbucket account if wasn't already
- Select it on left side and go to "SSH Key" section
- Choose "Create new..." option
- Key type ED25519 + your passphrase
- Push something using Xcode
- Enjoy

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use the Https:

The way I was able to fix this issue for me was using the "Caching Your GitHub credentials in git

In the command line, enter { gh auth login }, then follow the prompts

you can refer to the documents with in GitHub

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git