# Unable to push to phpfog, permission denied (publickey)

Tags: php, git, cloud, git-svn, phpfog

I am trying to host my php application over phpfog cloud services, this is my first ever try with any GIT client; following the procedure as defined in PHPfog documentations, I am done with creating keys and adding it.

Now when I am trying to clone my repo (git clone git@git01.phpfog.com:myrep.phpfogapp.com) over phpfog I am getting this error in git bash:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

however the public key has been generated and added into phpfog.

Kindly help, thankyou.

---

```
$ ssh -vT git@git01.phpfog.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to git01.phpfog.com [50.17.200.54] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Mypcname/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Mypcname/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Mypcname/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debia
n-3ubuntu7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'git01.phpfog.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Mypcname/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Mypcname/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Mypcname/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Mypcname/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git - Permission denied (publickey)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: Ive checked that thread, but didn't find solution of my problem.

Comment: and where is output of `ssh -vT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would retry uploading your ssh key again.

1. Delete the existing keys from the phpfog console.
2. print out your ssh key: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
3. create a new ssh key in the phpfog console and paste it in.