# Which Windows Shell command will print a file content on the standard output (like cat in Linux)?

Tags: windows, shell, cat

Which Windows Shell command will print a file content on the standard output (like cat in Linux) ?

With Google, Stackoverflow, etc, I just could not find a solution, but I am sure, there is an easy one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command is: `type <filename>`

However, if you want to Unix-fy your Windows shell there are [Win32 ports](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) of most of the command Unix style commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda hacky but I did this...

Download Git Bash for Windows.  This is very useful to open a linux style command prompt on windows.

Then, create a new git repository and add the file you wish to show to the git repo.  Then you can git show.

Let's say you have testFile.txt that you wish to show and it is located at "C:\Users\username\Desktop\FolderWhereFileIs"

```
cd "/c/Users/username/Desktop/FolderWhereFileIs/"
git add -A
git commit -m "Commit with all files"
git show testFile.txt
```