# How to setup a repo using GitHub for Windows with only an ssh key

Tags: github, repository, github-for-windows

I have installed GitHub for Windows and would like to use this gui to manage the repo that I'm setting up.

Right now I have the checkout command like this:

git clone ssh://blahblahblah/project

How can I set this repo up within GitHub for Windows?

Comment: I also don't want to create a github account since this is for a company repository and I'll be using Secure Git

Answer (score 0):

The normal procedure, described in [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-repositories-with-github-for-windows) is:

> You can add any repository already on your hard drive **by dragging the folder in from Explorer**.

It won't be able to connect to your (non-existent) GitHub account, but it would still display it.

That is: provided you put your public/private ssh keys at the right place:

```
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
```

(See "[Where does GitHub for Windows keep its SSH key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359867/6309)")