# ssh-agent suddenly "lost" my key

Tags: git, ssh

I'm using Git on Windows, and a week ago I set up my SSH keys. I cloned my repos and it worked fine.

Then, today I tried to make a pull and this happens:

```
$ git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried to run a `ssh-add-l` and returned this:

```
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

However my key files are on the same place. I faced this problem a while ago on a Mac, but then I just did another key and it worked. What can I do without generating another SSH key?

Comment: Are your keys still in HOME? (http://stackoverflow.com/q/20226147/6309)

Comment: @VonC no, it is somewhere else, however it is the same place when I set it up

Comment: Try and set `HOME` to that place (where there should be a `.ssh` folder), and launch G4W from that session.

Comment: you probably rebooted you machine.

Comment: @Jakuje well, I did...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ssh-agent` is not persistent across reboots. You need to start agent (equivalent to Linux `eval $(ssh-agent)`) and then you need to add them manually after reboot or setup some script to load them automatically.

If you have have your keys in "default location", like `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, it should be enough to run `ssh-add`, otherwise you need to run `ssh-add path/to/your/private/key`.

Comment: I'd think OP needs to both 1) have ssh-agent running (start it up) and 2) do ssh-add. That should do it.