# git bash in Windows 7

Tags: intellij-idea, tortoisegit, git-bash

I work on IntelliJ-idea on Windows 7.
I want to work on my program in the command line - git bash,
but I get errors
I tried to do pull then I got this error

```
$ git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I saw a solution in [Git - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey)
but they don't wrote about windows.

when I do push I asked about passphrase but when I write it I get an error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.    
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have the correct access because I can do pull, push.. from the folder (right click TortoiseGit..)

please your help
thank you

Comment: How you setup tortoise? To work via ssh or https?
And how do you cloned your repository from git bash?
You can check it via `git remote -v` command

Comment: all the things that i did until now, i did from the folder (right click on the folder - tortoiseGit ..)  .
this is what i get when i do `git remote -v` .
`$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:applango/applango.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:applango/applango.git (push)`

Answer (score 0):

So, there is no ssh publickey generated.
You must generate and register your rsa keys for github. Follow official [guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows).