# I can push but not pull git

Tags: git, gitlab

I just created a new git repo on Gitlab.

I init and pushed an already populated directory in the following manner:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:username/reponame.git
git add .
git commit -m 'first commit'

git push -u origin master
```

All worked as expected. However, when I try to pull back from the repo i get

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This error appears for:

```
git pull
git fetch
```

It does not appear for:

```
git push
```

Push is working fine, I have made several pushed several changes...

I did initially get my ssh password wrong a few times and attempted at first to push an empty repo.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Check on github for all commits they are really push or not .
Run `git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` .
 
For git pull ---->> `git pull origin master`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git - Permission denied (publickey)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so it appears.

Git init generated a FETCH_HEAD file that belonged to root. The rest of .git/ was my users.

I had to change the ownership of the file to my user an then the problem resolved.

Why it was not simply refusing me permission to access the file I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is an SSH error. SSH is used by Git when you use the `user@host:path` syntax, but the difference between `git pull` and `git push` comes *after* the authentication (and this error). So it's not a matter of push/pull, but it must be the way you call it (e.g. because you called `git pull` and `git push` from two different terminals with different environment variables set).

Can you run in a terminal:

```
git pull; git push
```

?

Actually, since this is only an SSH problem, you can also debug this using ssh itself:

```
ssh -vvv git@gitlab.com:username/reponame.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe an SSH error has occurred. [Troubleshoot the following](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/) :

1. Check that you are actually connecting to the server:
   `ssh -vT git@github.com`
2. Make sure you have the same key as what's being used:

   ```
   # start the ssh-agent in the background
   eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
   # Agent pid 59566
   ssh-add -l
   # 2048 a0:dd:42:3c:5a:9d:e4:2a:21:52:4e:78:07:6e:c8:4d /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
   ```
3. Double check your SSH keys: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys