# git permission denied (publickey) when verify connection

Tags: git, ssh

I get subject error when try to do following

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

.ssh permission

```
$ ls -al
total 33
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 MyUser AGL+Group(513)    0 Feb 27 16:53 .
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 MyUser AGL+Group(513)    0 Jan 10 16:12 ..
-rw-------  1 MyUser AGL+Group(513) 1667 Feb 28 18:01 .bash_history
-rwxr-xr-x  1 MyUser AGL+Group(513) 1494 Jan  9 20:45 .bash_profile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 MyUser AGL+Group(513) 6054 Jan  9 20:45 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 MyUser AGL+Group(513)   55 Feb 27 16:37 .gitconfig
-rwxr-xr-x  1 MyUser AGL+Group(513) 1919 Jan  9 20:45 .inputrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 MyUser AGL+Group(513) 1236 Jan  9 20:45 .profile
drwx------+ 1 MyUser AGL+Group(513)    0 Feb 28 17:46 .ssh
```

I did following steps before this

1. Generated ssh keys and stored in .ssh folder
2. Check ssh agent

   `$ ps aux |grep ssh

   7236       1    7236       7236  ?        1138370 18:26:09 /usr/bin/ssh-agent`
3. Added public key id_dsa.pub to github account through settings

`MyUser@PC000009416062 ~/.ssh
    $ ssh -v -T git@github.com
    OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
    debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
    debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
    debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
    debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
    debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/MyUser/.ssh/known_hosts:2
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_dsa for not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey).`

I tried following few solutions in this forum also but no luck.
I am using `Cygwin` to do this

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey)

[Solution 2](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/)

Comment: Verify your permissions. Could you please edit your post with the permissions of directory .ssh ?

Comment: Could you also edit your post with the full outpout of `ssh -v -T git@github.com` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/MyUser/.ssh/id_dsa for not in 
>   PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes

You generated `dsa` key, which is not supported by default. You need to add

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss
```

into your `~/.ssh/config`, or rather generate standard RSA keys, which work without issues.

Comment: I get `Bad key types '+ssh-dsa'. ` after adding that line to config

Comment: sorry, `dss` should be there. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

because it seems you're using dsa not the default rsa. you need to add a line to enable it in you ssh client config.

below are the message that I retrieved from this [link](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/29)

> rsa support is on by default but dsa/dss support is enabled by the following:
>
> Add line in your ssh client "config" file.
>
> `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2`
>
> -Name the config file "config" and place it in the users home directory/.ssh in windows.
>   /users/myname/.ssh/config
>
> `in the current build, the client config file is to be named ssh_config instead of "config"`
>
> The sshd server side should also have the following entry in sshd_config file:
>   PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2
>   restart the sshd server after making these changes

Comment: In my case since I am using `Cygwin ` , Should I update config file under `C:\cygwin64\home\MyUser\.ssh `? as I have few other `.ssh ` folders as well. Further since I am connecting to `github ` my account how I am doing the last step in your solution?

Comment: @MPH : yes, I think it should be in `C:\cygwin64\home\MyUser\.ssh`. For the second question, I think you can skip the last step because, it seems that github able to accept dsa key. (https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/)

Comment: I added the mentioned line with `# ` in front, because otherwise I get error ` /home/MyUser/.ssh/config line 49: Bad key types 'ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2'.  Further copy `ssh_config ` from `/etc ` to `.ssh ` folder and change the name to `config ` as specified. still same output for `$ ssh -v -T git@github.com `. Am I doing anything different?

Comment: hmmm, can you try to run `ssh -Q key` to check what kind of key types that your client supported?

Comment: ` $ ssh -Q key                                                                                                                                                   
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
 `

Comment: seems that `ecdsa-sha2` key type is not supported in your current version. Could you try to remove the value and try again