# What to do after git init? Seeking to create private GitLab repository and sync with local working site files?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have initialized a Git repository in local C:/pathtosite/.git/ ...

I've created a private repository on GitLab ...

My goal is to continue working on my site locally, but have version control ...

Hours later, I'm still having issues trying to understand what to do next ...

Answer (score 7):

You need to add your files and push them to your repository.

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@gitlab.domain.com:username/repository.git
git push -u origin master
```

## Step by step:

Add all files in repository

```
git add -a
```

Commit files (with commit message 'first commit')

```
git commit -m 'first commit'
```

add your remote gitlab repository(git@gitlab.domain.com:username/repository.git) as origin

```
git remote add origin git@gitlab.domain.com:username/repository.git
```

push your files to origin

```
git push -u origin master
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: getting error "On branch master Changes not staged for commit: deleted: foldername no changes added to commit" ...

Comment: also getting message "On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean" when I add folder mentioned ...

Comment: do you have files in your folder?
I will update my answer

Comment: yes I have my live site files in my folder (local C:/pathtosite)

Comment: if you execute git `remote -v ` do you see your git repository as origin ?

Comment: yes I see the correct <originurl>

Comment: what does `git status` say about the files?

Comment: `git add -a` should be `git add -A` sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107159/discussion-between-fupduck-and-faalbane).

Comment: `Permission denied (publickey)` happend.

Comment: @saeed see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you've run

```
git init
```

locally, and created a repository on GitLab? If so, the issue is that you're not quite following the standard workflows for git. You don't want to explicitly initialize your local git repository. Instead, [following the gitlab documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/gitlab-basics/command-line-commands.html):

1. Go to your repository page on gitlab
2. Copy the https URL it gives you on the right-hand side of the page
3. Take that URL, and run git clone the-url-goes-here one level above where you would like the local copy to go (i.e. if you want the repository in C:\my\gits\path\repo, run this command in C:\my\gits\path).

Once you do that, you'll have a local copy you can work in under version control. fupduck's answer below covers what you'll want to do once you have that repository working with regard to adding files and making changes.

Comment: Yeah. Normally I use this way as well. But the other way round should work as well ;)

Comment: Thanks for you help ... I remembered I have a student micro account with GitHub, installed GitHub desktop, dragged in live site folder and already am up and running, learning more about branches ... #Respect