# git clone fail info:permission denied(publickey)

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

the command

> git clone git@github.com*********

will failed with the info :

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have searched it on internet many times.
the answer usually is about that the public key is wrong or so on.
however when i try the command

> ssh -T git@github.com

it work..

and my id_rsa.pub is just added on github,and when i use the command above i can see the tags under my ssh key `Last used within the last day`

So i can't understand what is the wrong with my git.feel so bad T^T.My morning is just work on this problem and look for the solution.

My system is macOS

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you seen [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey)?  There are 22 answers, and they all look helpful.

Comment: Is that a private repository? Are you able to login to another server using your public key? (Do you understand well how to setup public key authentication in general?)

Answer (score 0):

this problem confused me a lot,even i have tried all the solution that i could find on internet,until the day i reinstall my computer by accident.
It works.
I guess some conf in my old system is wrong with the git.

Comment: I think there will be an easier and faster solution than reinstalling your computer...