# Git error Permission denied (publickey), couldn't paste publickey

Tags: git, ssh

Upon git pull on Mac terminal to GitHub, it returns an error `showing permission denied (public key)`

I've looked through this earlier stack overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey) but upon

```
cat id_rsa.pub | bcopy
```

it shows `no such file or directory`. what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> upon `cat id_rsa.pub | bcopy` it shows no such file or directory. what should i do?

- Make sure `$HOME` (Linux or Mac) or `%HOME%` (Windows) is set.
- Generate an ssh key (that will create `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` and `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- Make sure your public key is registered on the remote server side.

Follow for instance, depending on your remote repos server:

- [GitHub ssh key generation](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/) (your case)
- [BitBucket ssh key generation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html)
- [GitLab ssh key generation](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html)

Comment: I'm not great at config at all. what does it mean 'Make sure $HOME is set'?

Comment: You are on Mac, so it should be OK. You can check with typing in a shell echo $HOME.