# Ansible: "Permission denied (publickey)" when using git module

Tags: git, github, ansible

I am trying to execute a git clone command in my Ansible playbook. It looks like this:

```
- name: a play that runs entirely on the ansible host
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: check out a git repository
    git: repo={{ repo_url }} dest=/Dest/For/Cloning/ accept_hostkey=yes
    vars:
      repo_url: git@github.com:lorin/mezzanine-example.git
```

And, my cfg file looks like this:

```
[defaults]
transport = ssh

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args= -A
```

However, when I'm running the command: `ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local GitClone.yaml`, I get the `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

I want to clone a gh repo to my local[specified file path].

Comment: What is the result of `ssh -T git@github.com`? Do you have GitHub account at all?

Comment: `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: I need to set it up, I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you want to clone someone else's public repo and likely never to push back to GitHub.

You don't need to provide GitHub credentials for that, so just use the HTTPS transport:

```
repo_url: https://github.com/lorin/mezzanine-example.git
```

---

As a side note: when you use `-c local` in the `ansible-playbook` call you override `transport` settings from the `ansible.cfg`. Settings in your example file are ignored.

Comment: Thanks. :) . It worked. How do I do it for my own repo? Which I'll keep pushing to.