# GitHub: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly while cloning directory from GitHub

Tags: git, hadoop, github, hipi

I am trying to clone directory of hipi from GitHub to my Ubuntu System using command 'git clone git@github.com:uvagfx/hipi.git' but it's showing an error as  Cloning into 'hipi'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
How to solve this error ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Checked almost every option posted here .. but what I found useful is backing up database from cpanel and files from file manager and then restoring it .

Answer (score 0):

If you clone to a directory where you have user permission ( /home/user/git) it will work fine.

Comment: Also you should set the SSH key !

Comment: Tried this but still I am getting same error . I think it's related to authentication of public keys . Do you have any idea about it . Note- already saved SSH keys in profile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey?rq=1 try this link it's bit similar. You'll find something useful there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTPS version for cloning. That will require you Git Credentials instead of using ssh keys.

`git clone https://github.com/uvagfx/hipi.git`