# Permission denied (publickey). GitHub -- Using a hotspot

Tags: github, permissions

I'm trying to push to GitHub, I recently moved, so I'm using my phone as a hotspot, I think this may be the culprit, but I'll run

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Then get

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Thoughts? As an experienced developer and GitHub user, this is a bit puzzling. Thank you guys for any help you can offer.

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: Still denied for some reason.

Comment: I think it could be because I'm using a hotspot, which I will be using for the next month or two -- so it's kind of important to me to be able to push code. I just don't know if me being on a hotspot is the culprit or not.

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with the hotspot, you have something else going on

Comment: Thanks for the input Keith M, I wasn't too sure. I'm just not sure how else to troubleshoot since I've been through all of GitHub's documentation, and I get the same result.

Comment: I've made some changes, now I've been authenticated, but now I get "You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access"