# can't able to perform git push, permission denied?

Tags: github, git-push

1. I already made a repository in github as wordpress-template.
2. I created a .git repository locally, added some files there, and committed it.
3. Then I created a remote as origin and give it the url of the github repository as:

   ```
   git remote add origin git@github.com:squalporeover/wordpress-template.git
   ```
4. Now I want to push my master branch to that repository. I ran the following command:

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```
5. But it shows:

   > Permission denied (publickey).
   >   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
   >
   > Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   >   and the repository exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: It seems to be duplicate but those kind of answer  not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you added the SSH version of the remote URL. In order to use this you need to [set-up Github with SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

Otherwise use the HTTPS version of the clone URL which will ask for your username and password:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ssh-keygen to generate an ssh key pair.
See: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Duplicate found here: [Git - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Step 1- git remote rm origin

Step 2-[select the http option in github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqWnr.png)

step 3- run the following command again

git remote add origin https://github.com/yourdirectory/link.git

git branch -M main

git push -u origin main