# I get an error whenever I use this code: git clone git@github.iu.edu:manoo/csci36300-git-example17.git

Tags: git, command-line, terminal

The error message on git clone is:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: The message is clear either ther url is incorrect or the public key doesn’t have the permission to access the repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a private GitHub instance, go to your github.iu.edu profile page, and double-check you have [registered your public key to your account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

Then [double-check ssh is working](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/) with:

```
ssh -T git@github.iu.edu
```

Comment: Using the `git@` command is specifying SSH as the connection protocol. This requires a key to the repository (host).

Comment: @ThomParkin Yes, that is what I meant with "double-check you have registered your public key to your account.", since it does indeed "requires a key to the repository (host)"