# Cannot push to Github from command line

Tags: git, github

I have setup key access to Github. Everything works well when I push from Git Bash command line. However I cannot use it from the command line. When I do a ssh -T git@github.com from command line, it says

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

If I do a git push it says

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know that the keys are correct and the repository exists because it works fine from git bash. Any ideas?

Comment: You either don't have an SSH agent running, or the agent doesn't know your SSH key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 1):

That could be one of two reasons: 1. you are not setup with a SSH key, which you have to get from git or the SSH key isn't linked to your account. I would recommend you try the `HTTPS` format from git instead of the `SSH`.

Help here:
https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

And there is even a github page for your question: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

Comment: Thanks. I have setup the keys properly if not it will not work with Git Bash right? HTTPS is what I use usually, but I don't like to type in username and password always. I know credentials can be stored but I don't like to do that. I want to do it the recommended way from my windows command line.

Answer (score -1):

Check in your terminal, whether SSH agent is running or not, using following command :-

`eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`, if its not running, which seems to be the issue. then add your private keys to the **ssh-agent** using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` , where id_rsa is your private key.

After adding, your private keys to ssh-agent, verify its been added successfully or not using `ssh-add -l` command.

Comment: No one has specified the system.

Comment: @MattSom , which system you are referring to ??