# ERROR when uploading app in IONIC PRO platform

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying  to upload an app in my IONIC PRO account (https://dashboard.ionicjs.com/apps).

In the ionic app folder when I try "git push ionic master" I get the error:
"*Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.*"

Other informations:

**1. My technologies:**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
Node : v7.3.0
npm  : 3.10.10 
OS   : macOS Sierra
```

Misc:
    backend : pro

**2. IONIC PRO account type:**
At this time I'm using the FREE (kickstarter) accouny type

**3. IONIC VIEW app**
I have installed the new *IONIC VIEW* app (the one with the blue background icon) for keeping track of my uploaded apps in IONIC PRO account

My questions:

1. What sould I do in order to be able to upload the app in my account?
2. Is it necessary to make other settings or to create another account type?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `SSH public key authentications` correctly on your project's `Git` repo.

You can see how to do that [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the ssh key but still doesn't work. I have also added this key in the Ionic Pro account. Is this correct?

Comment: You need to follow this doc: http://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/basics/getting-started/