# Can't get past Permission denied (publickey) on git-bash

Tags: linux, git, ssh, centos

I am trying to setup my SSH key for my internal git account and to also use to to connect to external SSH / SCP servers, but when I try to test this I am stuck at `Permission Denied (publickey)` error and no matter

What am I missing? I have followed - https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/ and other associated articles. I have also read numerous articles on stack.

This is the step I use to start, check and then test the connection before I push the repository, upon which I get `'Fatal' error for unable to pass authentication - on github. While when trying to connect to the external server (CentOS on AWS) using SSH, I get -'Disconnected: No supported authentication method available (Server sent:  publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).'`

Connect:
eval `ssh-agent -s`

Add:
ssh-add

Test:
ssh-add -l -E md5

Test:
ssh -T git@github.com

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the input @jww, I will keep in mind. This issue came up while doing development and during sharing a code repo on internal git.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Do the following commands**
`cd ~/.ssh`
`ssh-keygen` (hit enter for all the prompt to ask save)
`cat id_rsa.pub`

Then copy content in `id_rsa.pub` in your git-hub / stash account (ssh key)

Then it should work.

Comment: Thanks @smilyface that solved it.. at least part of it. Also took help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey .. last remaining part is error Disconnected: No supported authentication method available (Server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).'

Comment: Please mark as right answer if it solved your question !! :)