# git: cannot push on GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I created a repository on GitLab and I have a local project.

From:  `git remote -v` I get:

```
origin  git@gitlab.com:projects/MyPrj.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:projects/MyPrj.git (push)
```

When I try to push it to the repository with:

```
git push origin master
```

I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can access the repository with a web browser, but not from git from the command line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using SSH authentication, it might be worth trying HTTPS, to check if that's the issue. (I'm by no means a Git whiz, so I can't provide anything beyond passing that on).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: For me helps to change project path from `git@gitlab.com:...` to `https://gitlab.com/...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what is your remote URL associated with your local cloned repo:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote -v
```

Depending on its scheme (https or ssh), you will need to make sure your authentication is correctly set.

- https: you will need to enter your credentials once in order to cache them in the git credential helper (check what `git config credential.helper` returns)
- ssh: make sure you have a `/path/to/home/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` files (public and private rsa SSH keys, with the public key content registered on your remote hosting service.

If this is SSH (on Linux), you need to follow "[GitLab and SSH keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/) " and generate a new set of SSH keys with:

```
ssh-keygen -P "" -s -t rsa
```

Then copy the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` content on GitLab.