# Permission denied for public git repo on windows

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh

There are a lot of questions about this error, but I even get it for a public git repo. I'm a little bit lost about how to track down the issue.

```
PS C:\dev> git clone git@github.com:golang/dep.git
Cloning into 'dep'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a private or public repo. If you want to use ssh, you need to configure your ssh key. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2643584/9083959

Answer (score 0):

This may because you haven't configured your ssh key as expected.

- If you only need to **clone** the repository, you can try with *https* protocol.
- Otherwise, you can configure your ssh key follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2643584/5101757).