# How can I publish my vue project on github pages?

Tags: git, vue.js, github, npm, github-pages

I'm trying to publish a stock vue project that created by following command;

> vue create test

And I'm following the steps which is on the Vue's official website deployment [page](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages).

I'm having a problem when I try to run that command;

> bash deply.sh

It builds perfectly but after that I get the following;

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/muratcansenturk/test/dist/.git/
[master (root-commit) 3f9dbf9] deploy
 10 files changed, 28 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 css/app.3ed01e45.css
 create mode 100644 favicon.ico
 create mode 100644 img/logo.82b9c7a5.png
 create mode 100644 index.html
 create mode 100644 js/about.078d8f6d.js
 create mode 100644 js/about.078d8f6d.js.map
 create mode 100644 js/app.db0cb1ce.js
 create mode 100644 js/app.db0cb1ce.js.map
 create mode 100644 js/chunk-vendors.4a2cfde4.js
 create mode 100644 js/chunk-vendors.4a2cfde4.js.map
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Because of that problem I haven't been able to publish any kind of project on Github Pages.

Before that problem I just run npm run build then commit files to Github and open on gh-pages successfully.

Also my repo is [here](https://github.com/snturk/test).

Comment: Its seems to be a permission error to your repository. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate and upload an SSH key to github to authenticate commands that read and modify the remote repo.

Check out github's help docs on how to do that.

https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent