# GitLab SSH Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, macos, ssh, gitlab

I've followed the Gitlab instructions to set up an SSH key.

After everything is completed, I test my settings with

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

but then I got an error with

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (public key).
```

I also tried `ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.com` to find out the problems, as below. 
But I can't figure out how to fix it, does anybody have an idea, or could share suggestions?
Thank you very much!

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
.......
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/brandon/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/brandon/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/brandon/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/brandon/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/brandon/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/brandon/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/brandon/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:uOKjKpgEmnKqrFAS05Ccy8+B3Uw0kzSpurUpOgH0l3k
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/brandon/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/brandon/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Thank you for your patience in reading my post.

Comment: Can you run ls -lh ~/.ssh/ to review your SSH keypair against https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#review-existing-ssh-keys ?

Comment: From the ssh logs, it used `/Users/brandon/.ssh/id_ed25519` to authenticate with Gitlab. Is this the same SSH public key you [added to your Gitlab account](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account)?

Comment: What file should ssh be using to authenticate with github? In other words, what key did you set up with github? What file is that key stored in?

Comment: @AlekseyTsalolikhin It states
total 24
-rw-------  1 brandon  staff   419B  5  7 02:16 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r--@ 1 brandon  staff   108B  5  7 02:16 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-r--r--@ 1 brandon  staff   186B  5  7 02:17 known_hosts

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes it is, but then I don't know why it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Kenster I set up with id_ed25519.pub key, and it stored in /Users/brandon/.ssh

Comment: Have you checked all the answers here: [How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2643502/2745495)?

Comment: @GinoMempin Thank you. Im still trying, but so far hasnt solve my problem yet.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you, I solved it! 
Since its server is from our university so after changing 
`ssh -T git@gitlab.com` to `ssh -T git@theuniversitylink.com` it works.

I appreciate a lot for all the sharing and helps.

Comment: Does a `ssh -Tv` shows if the id_rsa is accepted? or  `id_ed25519`?

Comment: @VonC yes it did!

Answer (score 1):

> set up with id_ed25519.pub key, and it stored in /Users/brandon/.ssh

Try first with a more classic rsa key, for testing!

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM
```

Copy the /Users/brandon/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to your GitLab SSH account settings, and check if `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` works.

Comment: Hi thanks ! I tried it, but still the same results with public key(denied)

Comment: @BrandonTW Did you properly registered the content of `id_rsa.pub` to your account? As one continuous line?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it this way on macos:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```