# gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed GIT

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, bitbucket

Everything was working fine but suddenly I am getting the error:

> fatal: unable to access
> 'https://username@bitbucket.org/name/repo_name.git/':
> gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed

I am getting this on my computer as well as an EC2 instance. When I tried on another computer then it is working fine there.

I have tried many solutions from Stackoverflow and from other forums. but nothing worked!

On the computer, os is Linux mint 17 and on EC2 instance, Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS.

What can be the issue and what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: I face the same problem. My workaround is to rerun the command until it succeeds or to use SSH instead.

Comment: I rerun the command multiple times and no success and even a new clone using ssh is not working and I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quickest solution is to use **SSH** instead of **HTTPS**. I tried other ways to fix the issue but it was not working.

The following are steps to replace **HTTPS** from **SSH**:

1. Generate [ssh key using ssh-keygen](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html) on the server.
2. Copy the public key from the generated id_rsa.pub file from step 1 and add it at following links depending on the repository host -

   Bitbucket - https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/ssh-keys/

   Github - https://github.com/settings/ssh/new

   Gitlab - https://gitlab.com/profile/keys
3. Now run the following command to test authentication from the server command line terminal

   **Bitbucket**

   ```
   ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
   ```

   **Github**

   ```
   ssh -T git@github.com
   ```

   **Gitlab**

   ```
   ssh -T git@gitlab.com
   ```
4. Go to the repo directory and open .git/config file using emac or vi or nano
5. Replace remote "origin" URL (which starts with https) with the following -

   For **Bitbucket**  -  git@bitbucket.org:<username>/<repo>.git

   For **Github**  -  git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git

   For **Gitlab** - git@gitlab.com:<username>/<repo>.git

Answer (score 8):

Ran into the same issue on a server with Ubuntu 14.04, and found that on Aug 24, 2020 bitbucket.org changed to no longer allow old ciphers, see https://bitbucket.org/blog/update-to-supported-cipher-suites-in-bitbucket-cloud

This affects https:// connections to bitbucket, but does not affect ssh connections, so the quickest solution for me was to [add an ssh key to bitbucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/), and then change the remote from https to ssh.

The steps to change the remote I found from [here](https://pandammonium.org/how-to-change-a-git-repository-from-https-to-ssh/), and they are essentially:

```
# Find the current remote
git remote -v

origin  https://user@bitbucket.org/reponame.git (fetch)
origin  https://user@bitbucket.org/reponame.git (push)

# Change the remote to ssh
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:reponame.git

# Check the remote again to make sure it changed
git remote -v
```

There is more discussion about the issue on the Atlassian forums at https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/fatal-unable-to-access-https-bitbucket-org-gnutls-handshake/qaq-p/1468075

Comment: Great answer. I would also add it was helpful for me to get info on how to check if I have a SSH key as well as add that key to my git provider -- see this link for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42641637/1818235

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo bash

mkdir upgrade

cd upgrade

wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz

tar xpvfz openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz

cd openssl-1.1.1g

./Configure 

make ; make install

cd ..

wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.72.0.tar.gz

tar xpvfz curl-7.72.0.tar.gz

cd curl.7.72.0

./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl

make ; make install

cd ..

git clone https://github.com/git/git 

cd git

vi Makefile, change prefix= line to /usr instead of home

make ; make install
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Had to a install a few sudo-apt get packages and it worked well! Great answer.