# Git Permission denied (public key) but public key is added and working

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh

Hello I am facing issue to use `git push origin master` or `git pull origin master` because my remote origin is using SSH to connect, I have already setup SSH key pair configurations I also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git) solution but it is not working for me. To test connection I issued following command on Ubuntu

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

and it shows the following message

> Hi zain! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
> provide shell access.

I am confused if my authentication is working with the SSH test command then why it is not working with push or pull procedure

Error is following

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read
> from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Comment: What is the error you get when pushing or pulling?

Comment: check the question again i added the error

Comment: Are you connecting using the correct user?

Comment: yup . but wait a min why do i need a user when using ssh authentication?

Comment: Did you start the ssh-agent and load the private key using ssh-add?

Comment: No i did not because i mapped the ssh key in config file so i assume it is loading correct private file .

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/github/authenticating-to-github/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey) for troubleshooting tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because I mapped the ssh key in config file so i assume it is loading correct private file

Make sure your remote URL is actually using that .ssh/config entry, and the right private key.

Try:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv' git push
```

And see what exact key is used.

If you have a .ssh/config like:

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
```

Your URL should be:

```
gh:<me>/<myrepo>
```

> loading correct private file

An `ssh-agent` is only needed of your private key is passphrase-protected, and has nothing to do with the `~/.ssh/config` file
.