# 'Read-only file system' error when using kubernetes secret for ssh auth

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, ssh-keys, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to establish `SSH` authentication between Jenkins and GitHub. For the same, I am using the kubernetes secret to store the private and public key and I am mounting the secrets when the pod is created. Command I have used to create the secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic test-ssh --from-file=id_rsa=id_rsa --from-file=id_rsa.pub=id_rsa.pub --namespace jenkins
```

and mapped it in pod configuration as:

```
volumes:
  - secretVolume:
      mountPath: "/root/.ssh"
      secretName: "test-ssh"
```

When the pod is created, I can see that the secret is mapped correctly in the `~/.ssh` folder as shown below.

[image]

but the problem is the `~/.ssh` folder itself has the sticky bit permission enabled

[image]

and this is preventing the builds adding the `known_hosts` file when `ssh-keyscan` command is executed

```
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
bash: ~/.ssh/known_hosts: Read-only file system
```

I was hoping to achieve one of the two solutions I can think of

1. Remove the sticky permissions from `~/.ssh` folder after it is created
2. While mounting the kubernetes secret, mount it without sticky permissions

Could anyone help me to understand if there is a possibility to achieve this?
I have already tried `chmod -t .ssh` and it gives me the same error `chmod: changing permissions of '.ssh': Read-only file system`

The owner of the `~/.ssh` folder is `root` and I have logged in as `root` user. I have confirmed this by running the `whoami` command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secrets aren't mounts that allow for permissions to be alter, so you have to do some trickery to get it to work.
Recently I ran into a similar issue, and had to make it work.  We use a custom image to perform the ssh calls, so we added the .ssh dir and the known_hosts files to the image; setting the permissions in the Dockerfile.  I then used the subPath to target the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files in the deployment.  I don't have my mappings handy but can tomorrow if necessary to show what I mean.
I think the 'official' answer was to mount the files in a different location and cp them where they needed to be in an initContainer using a shared mount or in the entrypoint file/binary.