# Why am I getting "permission denied (publickey)" when trying to push to my repository on Github?

Tags: git, ssh, public-key, git-remote

I'm on Windows, using Git for Windows 2.40.0.windows.1
I've wanted to use SSH rather than HTTPS to connect to Github, so I've set up an SSH keypair, and added the public key to my Github profile.
I have set up the SSH Agent service and added my private key to it. `Get-Service ssh-agent` confirms that the agent is running. `ssh-add.exe -l` confirms that my key is added to the agent. When running `ssh -T git@github.com` as the [SSH key setup](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection) suggests, I am successfully authenticated.

The key is not stored at the standard `~/.ssh/id_rsa` location and it has a passphrase. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I think I should add this anyway.

*However*, after adding the SSH remote URL to my project, it gives me the familiar `permission denied (pubickey)` whenever I run `git push`:

```
PS > git push origin main
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This issue also happens with Gitlab, assumedly with any SSH connections to git remotes. Notably though, this issue does not happen with git when I use it on a Linux system, so this leads me to believe this is a problem with Git for Windows or my setup specifically.

What can I do here? Is there any configuration I've overlooked? How can I get more information from the `git push` command? (adding `--verbose` doesn't really add any more output)

Comment: Can you share the complete console log you get from `git push`?

Comment: @someone I've edited the post to include the command output

Comment: OK, not as informative as I hoped! Can you share `git remote -v` output as well?

Comment: I suspect that you may be using two separate ssh installations - one is system-wide and another one is bundled with git.

Comment: @someone it's about what you'd expect: URL to the repository with the SSH format for both push and fetch.

Comment: @user7860670 that sounds plausible. Is there any way to tell git to use the system's SSH installation rather than its bundled one?

Comment: It can be configured during Git for Windows installation. There should be some sort of "Select ssh executable" step which allows selecting external ssh client.

Comment: This question seems to be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/61163458/7860670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by user7860670's comment, Git for Windows comes with its own version of SSH bundled. Thus, whenever I used git commands, it would ignore my SSH agent configuration because I haven't used the bundled SSH agent.

The solution is to configure Git for Windows to use an external SSH command rather than its bundled one. This can be set during installation or by running the setup file again.