# Unable to connect Github ssh after restart

Tags: github, ssh

I try setup my Github Ssh key by follow step from https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account. At first everything works OK.

But after restart my computer, using git repository gives error : Error: Permission denied (publickey).

I create a new Github repository run git clone, but it still return the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems a duplicate of [Git: How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)

- Ensure the ssh-agent is running by running `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`
- Add the key by running `ssh-add ~/.ssh/{key_name}` where key_name is your key file name you generated (example: id_ed25519)
- You may want to consider creating or appending below to `.ssh/config`

```
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/{key_name}
```