# Why does git clone works fine, but then git push gives "Permission Denied (Public Key)"

Tags: github, ssh, console, ssh-keys

As in the title.
What I did :

1. `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`

   result:

   `Agent pid 457`
2. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/sshKey`
   Works fine.
3. `ssh-add -l -E sha256`
   Gives proper key from the folder.
4. `git push origin master`

   result:

   `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

`ssh git@github.com` works fine. (info about successful auth but not providing shell access)

I tried the same thing with the addition of testing if git clone works on the same repo. -  It does.

I also made a brand new SSH key and added it to my account but it resulted in the same error as in '4.'.

I expect to do a proper git push and save my progress.

Comment: Have you checked the [Github troubleshooting guide](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey)?

Comment: Yup. :) 
Did everything on the list. It should work theoretically.

Comment: Have you set the user name and email in the `.gitconfig`? Also this thread might help [Git: How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)

Comment: If you mean `git config` command then yes - I set up name and email

Comment: Run with ssh debug output: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push` and check what that does and what `ssh -vvv git@github.com` uses. Silly question, but do you have write permission to the repository?