# Ionicons Issue when building app with expo & react native when running eas build --platform android

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

when I run eas build --platform android I get the error:

```
Running "npm install" in /home/expo/workingdir/build directory

[stderr] 
npm
[stderr] 
ERR! code 128
[stderr] 
npm ERR!
[stderr] 
An unknown git error occurred
[stderr] 
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons.git
[stderr] 
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.113.4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
[stderr] 
npm
[stderr] 
ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
[stderr] 
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[stderr] 
npm ERR! 
[stderr] 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[stderr] 
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
[stderr] 
[stderr] 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     /home/expo/.npm/_logs/2023-08-17T01_24_52_670Z-debug-0.log
npm install exited with non-zero code: 128
```

It seems like the issue has to do with the react native vector Ionicons. But the library is fully up to date and so is my eas-cli. Here is how the Ionicons are used:

```
tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
       let iconName;
       if (route.name === "Search") {
         iconName = focused ? "home" : "home-outline";
       } else if (route.name === "Profile") {
         iconName = focused ? "person" : "person-outline";
       }
       return (
         <Ionicons
           name={iconName}
           size={32}
           color={color}
           style={{marginTop:19}}
         />
       );
     }
```

Also, this was working before I added a tab navigator with the icons to the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)