# can't "git push" to gitlab remote repository by ssh authentication

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I tried to push to remote repository to gitlab, I got error message like below.

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I already share public key to gitlab and I made a repository to push.

I think it might indicate that I have problem ssh connection.
However, I've done ssh connection configuration correctly.

Actually, I did connection test(`ssh -T gitlab`) then I got successful message

```
Welcome to GitLab, @MYUSERNAME!
```

And I write config in `~/.ssh/config` like

```
Host gitlab 
     Hostname gitlab.com
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/conf.d/personal/id_ed25519_gitlab
```

I read [official document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html) about ssh connection.

And I tried to remake my key and reflect that config to gitlab.
It seems to work when connection testing, but not to work when pushing to remote repository.

I cannot handle this problem at all, please help about this.

Comment: What is the ownership / permissions on the remote repo? Does `eval $(ssh-agent); ssh-add ~/.ssh/conf.d/personal/id_ed25519_gitlab` change anything?

Comment: @Brian61354270  It seems to change nothing...
Sorry I'm not understand well yet about git. Please teach me what ownership / permissions on the remote repo is.
I followed the guide below and stacked in setting remote repo.

https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2022/10/24/publishing-an-astro-site-with-pages/

Comment: Please run `git remote -v` and show us the result.

Comment: What if you modify your `~/.ssh/config` file and put `Host gitlab.com` instead of `Host gitlab`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)