Github keys are never recognised. It says they don't exist, but I can see them in the SSH folder
I am getting this error

PS F:\Xampp\htdocs\website.com> git push git@github.com: Permission
denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
exists.

I've been in Bash and Powershell trying different things. I have generated new keys and added them to GitHub but I still get the same outcome. In PowerShell I do this
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
PS C:\Windows\system32> # Enable the SSH agent service
>> Set-Service -Name ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
>>
>> # Start the SSH agent service
>> Start-Service ssh-agent
>>
PS C:\Windows\system32> ssh -T git@github.com
>>
Warning: Permanently added the ED25519 host key for IP address '20.26.156.215' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Content ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip
>>
PS C:\Windows\system32> Test-Path ~/.ssh
True
PS C:\Windows\system32> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "eoin@squareballoon.co.uk" -f ~/.ssh/github
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "~/.ssh/github" failed: No such file or directory

Still no joy.
Bash shows this
Eoin@Eoin-Ryzen MINGW64 ~
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
total 45
drwxr-xr-x 1 Eoin 197121    0 Sep 10 12:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 Eoin 197121    0 Oct  8 20:30 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 Eoin 197121  124 Sep 10 12:05 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 Eoin 197121 3389 Sep  8  2020 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 Eoin 197121  750 Sep  8  2020 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 Eoin 197121 1035 Oct  8 20:41 known_hosts

Eoin@Eoin-Ryzen MINGW64 ~
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Eoin@Eoin-Ryzen MINGW64 ~
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Whatever way I go I just some sort of "not allowed" or "doesn't exist" error.

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git

I believe this is a totally different error because my SSH keys are on a different drive to my htdocs folder.  That's why they don't exist even though I can see them.  Watch this space.

I don't use Windows, so you may need to tweak this. On a Unix shell, add -v to ssh to connect: ssh -vT git@github.com or try with git: GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git ... Also, if you create a new key, make sure your ~/.ssh/ directory exists (you seem to do that, but I don't know how Powershell interprets the ~) and git uses that (check ~/.ssh/config). But, why do you create a new key? You'll have to add that new key to github in the browser before github will accept it.

Also, ssh is really finicky about directory permissions. Try chmod 700 ~/.ssh and chmod 600 ~/.ssh/* to give only the owner any permissions. The debug logging from my previous comment may hint at that. Again, I don't know how Windows handles this.

I ended up paying  someone to help me, and we were able to resolve it.  I've added the answer for anyone else struggling with the same issue.

The reason I could see the keys but the terminal could not is because at some point I moved my files to a new location on my computer (F:), but the SSH keys were on the old drive (C:).  This is where the HOME drive is too, so I didn't want to change that.
So whenever I was running checks in the terminal, it was failing.  But as part of my troubleshooting, I had gone down a Google/Stack/ChatGPT wormhole looking for answers. I was following advice to use PowerShell and Bash.  Those two things were looking in C: and finding the RSA keys and reporting them as true (existing).  Terminal was still saying they didn't exist.
This is what I hadn't realised at the time.  My terminal was in the directory of the website.
Once I had gone through the troubleshooting steps above in the comments above (which I hadn't found in my previous searches), I suddenly noticed the mistake, which then helped me to understand the correct issue.
ssh-add C:\\Users\\Eoin/.ssh/github_rsa
This command allowed me to add a new SSH location on the other drive.  And from there it was a pretty simple thing to move it along.
